# Updating two rows in the same column with one string query sql

Tags: c#, sql, sql-update, where-clause

I'm trying to make an active row with value 1 change to 0 when activating another row (and turning the new row from 0 to 1) in the same table.

```sql
UPDATE SpecialTBL 
SET Active = 0 
WHERE Active = 1 AND SpecID = @SpecID;

UPDATE SpecialTBL 
SET Active = 1 
WHERE Active = 0 AND SpecID = @SpecID;
```

Both these works separately but I can't nestle them together.

Answer (score 3):

You can just use arithmetic:

```
UPDATE SpecialTBL 
SET Active = 1 - Active 
WHERE SpecID = @SpecID
```

If there may be other active values than 0 and 1, then we would need another filtering condition:

```
UPDATE SpecialTBL 
SET Active = 1 - Active 
WHERE SpecID = @SpecID AND Active in (0,1)
```

Else, a case expression is more conventional:

```
UPDATE SpecialTBL 
SET Active = CASE Active WHEN 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
WHERE SpecID = @SpecID AND Active in (0,1)
```

Comment: `~` feels more idiomatic than `1 -`, it also doesn't require an implicit cast to and from `int`

Comment: This solution removes the button I have activated but I'm still having the issue when activating another button. Instead of removing the already activated item it just piles the new item on top of it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the ~ bitwise NOT for BIT data type.

```
UPDATE SpecialTBL SET Active = ~Active
WHERE SpecID = @SpecID
```